# sql server group by different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my data looking like this

```
           Amount  Officer   Branch
             100       S1     B1
             200       S1     B2
             300       S1     B3
             100       S2     B1
             200       S2     B2
             300       S2     B3
```

I need another column which can show the totals by officer

```
           Amount  Officer   Branch  TotalByOfficer
             100       S1     B1       500
             200       S1     B2       500
             300       S1     B3       500
             100       S2     B1       900
             200       S2     B2       900
             600       S2     B3       900
```

Once i have this, I can use a having clause to filter by TotalByOfficer. 
How do I accomplish such a thing.

Comment: why isn't officer S1 total 600?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT amount, officer, branch, 
       SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY officer) as TotalByOfficer
FROM Table
```

Note, you can only use "HAVING" if you are using group by which I'm not.  Use this as a sub query and add a filter, like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT amount, officer, branch, 
         SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY officer) as TotalByOfficer
  FROM Table
) X
WHERE TotalByOfficer <> 500
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do a `SUM()` `OVER` a `PARTITION` on `Officer`:

```
Select  Amount,
        Officer,
        Branch,
        Sum(Amount) Over (Partition By Officer) As TotalByOfficer
From    YourTable
```